# get localStorage into a asp variable?

Tags: local-storage

Im setting a localStorage.setItem(persnr,'12345'); value and its working as it should.

But I wonder how can I get the value from the localStorage and put it in a .asp(classic) variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Javascript is run on the client. ASP is run on the server.